# Question on using L'Hopital's rule for this problem?

Tags: calculus, limits, indeterminate-forms

I'm doing some practice questions and I've encountered a wall. The question is:

> Find the limit of the function $(\ln4x-\ln(x+7))$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

the indeterminate form is $\infty-\infty$, so I'm not sure how to advance from here. I think I would like $f(x)/g(x)$ form, but I'm not sure how to do that in this situation. Can you give me a hint in the right direction?

I certainly don't want the answer.

Comment: What is $\ln(a)-\ln(b)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: $$\ln4x -\ln{(x+7)}=\ln\frac{4x}{ x+7}$$
from the [properties of the logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Logarithmic_identities).

Evaluate $\displaystyle \frac{4x}{x+7}$ and take the logarithm of your answer.

Comment: Actually it's $ln ( \frac{4x}{x+7} ).

Comment: i.e. the log of the entire expression.

Comment: Apologies edited now. Can we delete these comments?

Comment: I got the right answer. If you didn't answer, I wouldn't have known to evaluate the inside of the log first. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Hint:
$$\ln(a) - \ln(b) = \ln\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)$$

Comment: Don't forget to use \ln instead of ln to produce the proper non-italic text, e.g. $\ln$ vs $ln$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Apply properties of logarithms to get

$$\ln 4x-\ln (x+7)=\ln \frac{4x}{x+7}.$$